# Why is willpower part of the Emotional Spectrum?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Willpower as defined by wiktionary is

> The unwavering strength of will to carry out one’s wishes

This isn't really an emotion that a person feels. It's more of a mindset that someone has. As such, you can't really *feel* willpower like you could feel love or rage.

Why was willpower chosen as the "emotion" that powers the Green Lanterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Willpower isn't so much an emotion like the other colors. You can feel fear, rage, love, hope, etc... but not so much willpower.

But willpower (green) is the ability to control one's emotion and act independently of impulses, which is why it's in the middle of the spectrum. It balances extremes such as rage (red) and love (violet), which are often uncontrollable.

From [Emotional Spectrum: Colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_spectrum#Colors) wiki section:

> [Johns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoff_Johns) describes willpower (the emotion central to the spectrum) as
>   being the ability to maintain control over one's emotions and grow as
>   an individual.

From the [Green Lantern Willpower](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Willpower) wikia:

> Willpower is a light born of The White Light of creation, **but in fact
>   is not an emotion**, and is represented by the color green. Willpower is
>   in fact a mental ability rather than an emotion, and is defined as
>   "the control of one's impulses and actions".

This only explains how it fits in the emotional spectrum.

Comment: Don't forget *determination* - it's closely tied to willpower, and is an emotion.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write this as a comment, since I'm not very familiar with the universe, then decided to look it up.  On the [Green Lantern Corps](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Corps) page on the Green Lantern wikia is this quote:

> "**We must act now. Act with the *same* boldness and *courage* that our
>   *Lantern Corps* displays**" - The Guardians of the Universe

And according to wikipedia, [courage is an emotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emotions).

Comment: But willpower is what powers the green lantern corp. not courage.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Like I said, I'm not very familiar with it.  I always thought Green Lanterns were related to courage and/or justice, not willpower.  Courage also falters with fear, making the weakness to yellow match up, and there's additionally Black/White - Death and Life aren't emotions, either.  (Granted, those two are special.  Is Green special as well?)